# Cannot use FreeImage.Load and FreeImage.Loadex functions

Tags: c#, freeimage

I am using FreeImage dll to display jpeg2000 image file. but when I run some demo, all of them do not run success. they stop at first time I call FreeImage API function. (FreeImage.LoadEx, FreeImage.Load .., etc), everything are same with sample of FreeImage foundation.

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

I have a Form application, and I add FreeImageNet.dll as references. The FreeImage project I get lastet version from http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html and build. I let FreeImaged.dll and FreeImageNET.dll in same application file at runtime. In cs file I wrote:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!FreeImage.IsAvailable())
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Not exist");
     }
}
```

this messagebox always show. That mean FreeImage.dll did not add to my project. 
I cannot add this to my project, please help me.
My app is in x64 and library are x64, too.

Comment: Show us your code, please!

Comment: I showed my code, this is very simple, hope your help!

Comment: How do you know the library is x64? How do you know that the library name should be ``freeimage.dll``?